# How to join results of two commands in IBM AIX ksh

Tags: ksh, aix, command-substitution, join

I would like to perform script below but without creation of intermediate files (lsfs.out, df.out) on IBM AIX with ksh

```
lsfs_out=`lsfs | sed -n '1d;p' | sort -b -k 3`
df_out=`df -k | sed -n '1d;p' | sort -b -k 7`
echo "$lsfs_out" > lsfs.out
echo "$df_out" > df.out
join -1 7 -2 3 df.out lsfs.out
```

The output of the first command is like below:

```
lsfs | sed -n '1d;p' | sort -b -k 3
/dev/hd4        --         /                      jfs2  4194304 --         yes  no
/dev/hd11admin  --         /admin                 jfs2  1048576 --         yes  no
```

The output of the second command is:

```
df -k | sed -n '1d;p' | sort -b -k 7
/dev/hd4          2097152    836284   61%     9360     5% /
/dev/hd11admin      524288    523848    1%        7     1% /admin
```

I can't understand how to replace file names for "join" command with commands output.

What I was trying was useless. For example:

```
join -1 7 -2 3 <(echo "$df_out") <(echo "$lsfs_out")
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.
```

one more

```
join -1 7 -2 3 <`echo "$df_out"` <`echo "$lsfs_out"`
A file or path name is too long.
< some output >
Cannot find or open the file.
```

Comment: ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.

Comment: @Archemar the OP is using ksh, and it looks like it (or this version of it) doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: More recent AIX have ksh93 avails, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `awk` solution (can be onelined of course)

```
(df -k ; lsfs ) |
awk 'FNR==1 {next; }
     NF==7 { L[$7]=$0 ; next ; }
     { printf "%s %s\n",$0,L[$3];}'
```

where

- `FNR==1 {next; }` filter header
- `NF==7 { L[$7]=$0 ; next ; }` store df line indexed on filesystem
- `{ printf "%s %s\n",$0,L[$3];}` print lsfs line and join with df's
- this suppose no filesystem has a space in path (original problem also)